# SQL Server 2008: WHILE loop does not iterate every row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure using a `while` loop. It is supposed to read every record and give the result. I have 6 records returned which is right but it prints the result of the 6th record for 6 times.

```
DECLARE @num_month float, @RowCount int, @Init int

--Get count of SubrowID
SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(SubrowID) 
                 FROM   tblSubrow
                 WHERE SubrowID = 13)

SET @Init = 1

--Iterate each SubrowID
WHILE (@Init <= @RowCount)
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @num_month = SUBSTRING(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, s.StartDate, s.EndDate) * CAST(10 AS float) / CAST(30 AS float) / CAST(10 AS float) AS VARCHAR(10)), (CHARINDEX('.', DATEDIFF(DAY, s.StartDate, s.EndDate) * CAST(10 AS float) / CAST(30 AS float) / CAST(10 AS float), 1)), 2)
    FROM   
       tblSubrow  
    WHERE  
       SubrowID = '13'

    print @num_month

    SET @Init = @Init + 1
END
```

Comment: Maybe if you used the loop counter somewhere in the query, it would return a different value each time.  Often, when you run exactly the same query over and over you get the same results, even in a `while` loop, You may be confusing a simple `while` loop with a cursor.  Really, you should learn to use cursors if you want to do this type of processing.

Comment: What are you trying to loop here. How will you identify each row

Comment: I was told cursor is not recommended to use so I try to use while loop.  I need to loop 6 startdate and enddate from tblSubrow table.  They all have different startdate and enddate.

Comment: @angelcake *Any* WHILE loop or imperative (non-DQL) TSQL carries the same "not recommended" as a cursor. It moves the problem out of the (if used correctly) very-efficient RA and set-based realm. For some tasks, such as sequential processing, a loop is needed: then use it, and realize that a cursor is no more or less bad. They are both "not recommended" loops. (In the example code however, there is *no need* for an imperative loop, assuming print is replaced with useful output!)

Comment: [`FETCH NEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180152.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHILE loop select is always going to return 6 rows and your @num_month variable will end up being set to the last result row, namely the 6th one in this case.

I'm not sure of your requirements and why you need to encase this in a WHILE loop.

Using the result set to populate a table variable instead:

Assuming

1. [tblSubrowRowid] below is the primary key of the table, [tblSubrow].
2. s.StartDate and s.EndDate are columns in [tblSubrow]. (You did not alias [tblSubrow].)
3. Your calc for num_month is dictated by your requirements because that's not what you were asking about.

   ```
   DECLARE @updateTable AS TABLE ( [rowid] INT, [num_month] FLOAT );
   INSERT INTO @updateTable
       ( [rowid], [num_month] )
   SELECT 
       [tblSubrowRowid], SUBSTRING(CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, [StartDate], [EndDate]) * CAST(10 AS float) / CAST(30 AS float) / CAST(10 AS float) AS VARCHAR(10)), (CHARINDEX('.', DATEDIFF(DAY, [StartDate], [EndDate]) * CAST(10 AS float) / CAST(30 AS float) / CAST(10 AS float), 1)), 2)
   FROM   
      [tblSubrow]
   WHERE  
      SubrowID = '13';
   ```

Then you can use the data in @updateTable to update [tblSubrow] or another table as needed.

Always remember, SQL is set-based and it's best to use it that way.

Comment: I actually have some updates afterwards for each row in the entire store procedure and I need to iterate every record to do the update

Comment: You could use a temporary table / table variable to store the results and then update from there.

Comment: @angelcake, there is a 99.9% chance you do not need to iterate to do updates. You should not ever think in terms of iterating. Iterating is BAD. It costs performance. You need to learn to operate in sets. Iteration is a last ditch, nothing else works operation.

Comment: most of teh the suggested techniques in here work because a while loop is basically a type of cursor. http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the loop variable @Init in the query you have written inside the loop. I think you are expecting it to behave like a Cursor that'll automatically move the record once the loop is run, there is no such thing.

You should find a way to query the table based on the value you receive inside the loop. Or write the query to get a Top 1 value each time, put it in a temporary table and include a NOT IN clause in the query to look up and fetch the top value that is NOT present in the temporary table (i.e. exclude fetched already).